# How to further explore the effect of a covariate variable in a repeated measures ANOVA in SPSS?

Tags: repeated-measures, spss, predictor, controlling-for-a-variable

Using SPSS, I've fitted a model with a repeated measures ANOVA with those predictors:

- two within-subject variables
- many "covariate" variables

The effect I'm mostly care about is the interaction between the two within-subject variables. But I also threw into the pot several other variables as *covariates*, for two reasons:

1. I wanted to control for their possible effect.
2. I was interested whether one of those covariate variables could have a "moderating" effect over the interaction effect (which is the focus of my analysis).

When I examined the analysis results, I found that the interaction effect between the two within-subject variables (i.e., the effect I'm mostly care about) was non-significant. However, one *covariate* turned out to be significant, expressed as a 3-way interaction.

That is, if `X` and `Y` are the within-subject variables, and `Z` is one covariate (out of many), then the interaction `X*Y` was non-significant but `X*Y*Z` was significant.

Now, I'd like to further explore the relationship between `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, to better describe or interpret the meaning of `Z` being a significant covariate. Especially given the fact that `X*Y` had no significant effect but `X*Y*Z` did.

Using SPSS, what further steps can I take?

Notes:

1. I typically work with `R`, with packages designed to explore and visualize interactions (for example, `{interactions}` or `{ggeffects}`). By contrast, in SPSS I didn't find any clear tool for exploring 3-way interactions, or relationships of covariates, etc.
2. Talking about significance, I refer to a p-value threshold of 0.05. I'd like to put aside the entire discussion about significance and the arbitrariness of p < 0.05. I'm fully aware of that and have my own criticism about this method, but in this project I need to play ball with this paradigm.

---

### Reproducible example

**Description**

In this dataset, we have data about 80 people. Each row represents one person, whose id is in the `response_id` column. We have two within-subject variables as the independent variables. They're called `x` and `y`, and each of them is *categorical* with two levels. Because SPSS's *Repeated Measures* procedure requires that input data be in a certain format, I've wrangled the `x` and `y` variables into 4 columns that reflect the 4 combinations of their 2x2 relationship:

- `ws_x1_y1`
- `ws_x1_y2`
- `ws_x2_y1`
- `ws_x2_y2`

As for covariates, we have 10 of those. One is categorical with 2 levels (`covariate_dichoto`), and the other 9 are continuous (e.g., `covariate_cont_a`, `covariate_cont_b`, etc.)

**Reproducible code**

The following `R` code exports the data to a `.sav` file. Then follows the SPSS syntax.

```r
my_data <- structure(list(response_id = c("1_SMBS", "2_zMo6", "3_09fp", 
                                          "4_nDSQ", "5_J7N1", "6_cVxV", "7_scLw", "8_c9Ss", "9_vzPF", "10_v8Hq", 
                                          "11_K5cY", "12_mjAn", "13_ROCt", "14_39Ig", "15_kFx2", "16_DABh", 
                                          "17_IkBE", "18_F4Ea", "19_EV2X", "20_Nyqp", "21_HIJa", "22_CA7K", 
                                          "23_dcaB", "24_YAlL", "25_mkgg", "26_TUVo", "27_8FHw", "28_MTfQ", 
                                          "29_qL6q", "30_6Bz3", "31_5dyL", "32_BT8H", "33_dYUm", "34_trwA", 
                                          "35_zxDd", "36_vCvz", "37_pCyY", "38_4RU7", "39_va9P", "40_zwAo", 
                                          "41_xibi", "42_JYaT", "43_Adrc", "44_mSqj", "45_xf35", "46_qERb", 
                                          "47_dQxD", "48_noZu", "49_FmgD", "50_BvZr", "51_HDwD", "52_0C3Z", 
                                          "53_I6Th", "54_4oia", "55_1QGl", "56_FyqM", "57_Esib", "58_eTiv", 
                                          "59_2hTn", "60_bdvm", "61_0JfT", "62_h5Xy", "63_K94d", "64_zNQ8", 
                                          "65_2Kx5", "66_w4eb", "67_krO9", "68_NU9p", "69_uRkr", "70_G8XF", 
                                          "71_MgFp", "72_sf0L", "73_650g", "74_4iPZ", "75_tC6b", "76_ZHEy", 
                                          "77_HbFv", "78_LRXd", "79_aIxs", "80_3s67"), 
                          covariate_dichoto = structure(c(2L, 
                                                          1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                          2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                          1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                          1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                          2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
                                                                                                                                  "B"), class = "factor"), 
                          ws_x1_y1 = c(0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.266666666666667, 0.733333333333333, 1, 0.533333333333333, 0.733333333333333, 
                                       1, 0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.866666666666667, 1, 
                                       1, 0.266666666666667, 1, 0.533333333333333, 1, 1, 0.466666666666667, 
                                       0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0.866666666666667, 0.6, 0.6, 0.666666666666667, 
                                       0.933333333333333, 1, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.866666666666667, 
                                       1, 0.533333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0.866666666666667, 1, 
                                       0.933333333333333, 0.8, 0.733333333333333, 0.866666666666667, 
                                       0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.8, 0.866666666666667, 
                                       0.266666666666667, 0.866666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0.733333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0.866666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
                                       0.8, 0.466666666666667, 0.933333333333333, 1, 0.733333333333333, 
                                       0.266666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.866666666666667, 0.866666666666667, 
                                       0.666666666666667, 0.6, 0.466666666666667, 0.866666666666667, 
                                       0.933333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 1, 0.933333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0.533333333333333, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.466666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 
                                       0.666666666666667, 1, 0.2), 
                          ws_x1_y2 = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0.533333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.933333333333333, 1, 
                                       0.8, 0.866666666666667, 1, 1, 1, 0.4, 1, 0.2, 1, 0.933333333333333, 
                                       0.2, 0.6, 0.866666666666667, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.666666666666667, 
                                       0.933333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 1, 0.933333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 
                                       0.866666666666667, 0.933333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0.8, 
                                       0.866666666666667, 1, 0.933333333333333, 0.6, 0.8, 0.933333333333333, 
                                       0.8, 0.666666666666667, 0.8, 0.8, 0.333333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 
                                       0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 0.733333333333333, 
                                       0.933333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 1, 0.2, 1, 1, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0.666666666666667, 1, 0.733333333333333, 1, 0.733333333333333, 
                                       0.8, 0.533333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 
                                       1, 1, 0.4, 0.333333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0.6, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 0.6, 0.533333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 
                                       0.466666666666667), 
                          ws_x2_y1 = c(0.266666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0, 0.0666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0, 0.2, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.266666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0, 0.0666666666666667, 0.266666666666667, 0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0.2, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0.133333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 0, 0.266666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0, 0, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0.133333333333333, 0.4, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0.266666666666667, 0.2, 
                                       0, 0.2, 0.333333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.266666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.4, 0.4, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 0, 0.533333333333333), 
                          ws_x2_y2 = c(0.466666666666667, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0.133333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 0.266666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0, 0.133333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0.4, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0.266666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0.133333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0.266666666666667, 
                                       0.2, 0.133333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 0.266666666666667, 
                                       0.0666666666666667, 0.266666666666667, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.533333333333333, 0, 0, 0.466666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.266666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 
                                       0, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 
                                       0.266666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 
                                       0.4, 0.333333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 0.4, 0.6, 0.333333333333333, 
                                       0, 0.333333333333333, 0.4, 0, 0.333333333333333), 
                          covariate_cont_z = c(3.2, 
                                               2.2, 5.8, 3.6, 4.2, 3, 5.4, 3.2, 2.6, 4.4, 2.6, 4.4, 3, 3.2, 
                                               3.6, 1.6, 4.8, 3.2, 4.4, 1.4, 3.4, 4.6, 1.4, 3.6, 2.6, 4.8, 3.6, 
                                               5.2, 2, 2.2, 2.6, 2.6, 3, 5.6, 4, 4.2, 2.6, 2.8, 3.8, 7, 3, 4.2, 
                                               4.4, 3.2, 3.4, 5.4, 3.2, 2.8, 4, 6, 2.8, 4.2, 2.4, 1.2, 1.2, 
                                               2.8, 6.4, 4.2, 3.2, 4.4, 2.8, 4, 4.4, 4.2, 3.2, 4.6, 2.8, 2.4, 
                                               3.6, 3.6, 3.2, 3.2, 3.6, 5.2, 5.6, 2.4, 2.8, 3.6, 2.8, 5.6), 
                          covariate_cont_a = c(2.5, 1.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 
                                               4.16666666666667, 4, 4.16666666666667, 4.5, 3.33333333333333, 
                                               4.66666666666667, 3, 6.33333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 
                                               4.66666666666667, 4.5, 4.5, 4.33333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
                                               3.83333333333333, 1.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
                                               4, 3.5, 4.5, 5.33333333333333, 3.5, 2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
                                               3.5, 5.33333333333333, 4.5, 2.83333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 
                                               3.33333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 
                                               4.66666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 6.16666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 
                                               3.16666666666667, 5, 4.33333333333333, 5.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 
                                               3.5, 3.5, 3.83333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 1.5, 5, 3, 
                                               3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 
                                               4.83333333333333, 3.5, 2.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 
                                               5, 2, 2.66666666666667, 1, 5, 4, 3.16666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
                                               4.16666666666667, 3.83333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 2.5, 
                                               4.5, 2, 2.33333333333333), 
                          covariate_cont_b = c(27, 36, 34, 
                                               24, 34, 26, 26, 44, 42, 30, 37, 28, 28, 24, 36, 33, 32, 27, 
                                               33, 35, 32, 28, 32, 36, 46, 43, 34, 28, 38, 48, 32, 26, 30, 
                                               30, 32, 40, 34, 34, 28, 73, 28, 27, 27, 26, 48, 28, 31, 32, 
                                               24, 29, 43, 27, 27, 36, 38, 31, 48, 30, 28, 26, 27, 46, 31, 
                                               36, 86, 26, 39, 30, 30, 36, 27, 31, 26, 34, 27, 36, 35, 48, 
                                               27, 28), 
                          covariate_cont_c = c(46, 33, 27, 45, 36, 33, 49, 
                                               44, 47, 16, 6, 55, 35, 29, 37, 18, 26, 31, 37, 30, 21, 46, 
                                               31, 43, 31, 51, 36, 35, 25, 37, 45, 25, 34, 52, 59, 51, 29, 
                                               45, 43, 60, 41, 37, 60, 38, 44, 47, 25, 33, 24, 46, 48, 27, 
                                               42, 35, 18, 39, 36, 52, 30, 46, 5, 40, 23, 33, 69, 25, 38, 
                                               17, 58, 54, 49, 14, 37, 18, 45, 24, 19, 41, 30, 26), 
                          covariate_cont_d = c(4.875, 
                                               3.125, 4, 4, 3.375, 3.625, 4.375, 4.75, 3.375, 4.375, 4.125, 
                                               4, 4.75, 4, 4.125, 4, 4.375, 4.5, 3.875, 2.75, 4.375, 3.625, 
                                               4.5, 4.25, 4, 2.875, 4.5, 3.5, 4.125, 4.375, 3.75, 3.5, 4.125, 
                                               4, 4.625, 4.375, 4, 4, 4.375, 4.5, 3.25, 4.375, 4.125, 3.75, 
                                               4.5, 3.875, 4.625, 5, 4.25, 4.5, 3.5, 4.625, 4.375, 4.375, 
                                               3.375, 3.25, 4.75, 4.75, 3.625, 3.375, 3.625, 4.5, 3.375, 
                                               4.5, 4.5, 4.625, 4.625, 3.375, 4.75, 4.5, 3.75, 4.625, 4.5, 
                                               4.375, 3.75, 4.75, 4.625, 4, 4.5, 3.875), 
                          covariate_cont_e = c(4.16666666666667, 
                                               5.66666666666667, 5, 2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 
                                               4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 5, 
                                               6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
                                               5, 3.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 
                                               6.33333333333333, 6, 5, 5.5, 5.16666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
                                               4.5, 4.83333333333333, 3.16666666666667, 4.5, 5.16666666666667, 
                                               6.16666666666667, 5.5, 5.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
                                               5.5, 4.16666666666667, 6, 4.66666666666667, 5.5, 5.16666666666667, 
                                               4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 5.83333333333333, 4.5, 6.33333333333333, 
                                               4.16666666666667, 5.83333333333333, 7, 5.83333333333333, 
                                               4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 6, 6.33333333333333, 
                                               4.83333333333333, 6.16666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 4.5, 
                                               5.16666666666667, 6.16666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 
                                               4.83333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 6.16666666666667, 3.5, 
                                               5.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5, 
                                               5.66666666666667, 5, 6, 5.33333333333333, 5, 3.66666666666667, 
                                               6.83333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
                                               5.33333333333333), 
                          covariate_cont_f = c(3, 2, 6, 3.5, 2.5, 
                                               1.25, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2.25, 3.5, 4.25, 2.5, 2.25, 5.25, 3.5, 
                                               4.25, 1.75, 5, 1.75, 1.75, 3.5, 1.5, 4.25, 3.25, 2, 3, 3.5, 
                                               2.5, 2.25, 1.25, 1.75, 1.25, 4.25, 1.25, 3.25, 1.5, 1.5, 
                                               4.5, 7, 1.25, 2.75, 6, 1.5, 5, 5.5, 1.75, 2.75, 2.25, 3.75, 
                                               3, 4.5, 2, 3, 3.25, 1, 4.25, 1.5, 1.75, 3, 2.25, 4.5, 2.75, 
                                               3.5, 2, 3, 2.5, 1.75, 1, 3.25, 3, 4.25, 1.75, 4.25, 3.75, 
                                               1.5, 1.5, 3.75, 2, 2.5), 
                          covariate_cont_g = c(4, 7, 7, 6, 
                                               5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
                                               5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 7, 1, 6, 6, 
                                               7, 4, 7, 5, 4, 7, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 
                                               3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6), 
                          covariate_cont_h = c(109, 131, 120, 133, 68, 135, 135, 113, 
                                               117, 124, 130, 126, 131, 119, 133, 132, 133, 126, 133, 135, 
                                               132, 120, 135, 117, 130, 124, 93, 131, 120, 126, 135, 128, 
                                               115, 134, 131, 130, 126, 130, 120, 61, 122, 132, 133, 124, 
                                               123, 119, 122, 131, 128, 118, 128, 122, 124, 132, 132, 135, 
                                               123, 134, 114, 133, 133, 96, 132, 134, 130, 133, 135, 116, 
                                               135, 129, 135, 128, 135, 108, 125, 132, 133, 70, 132, 126
                          )), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                     ))
```

```r
my_data
#> # A tibble: 80 x 15
#>    response_id covariate_dichoto ws_x1_y1 ws_x1_y2 ws_x2_y1 ws_x2_y2
#>    <chr>       <fct>                <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 1_SMBS      B                    0.133    0.333   0.267    0.467 
#>  2 2_zMo6      A                    0.267    0.333   0.133    0.2   
#>  3 3_09fp      A                    0.733    0.533   0        0     
#>  4 4_nDSQ      B                    1        1       0.0667   0     
#>  5 5_J7N1      B                    0.533    0.667   0.467    0.6   
#>  6 6_cVxV      A                    0.733    0.933   0.133    0.0667
#>  7 7_scLw      B                    1        1       0        0.133 
#>  8 8_c9Ss      A                    0.667    0.8     0.2      0.133 
#>  9 9_vzPF      B                    0.533    0.867   0.0667   0.267 
#> 10 10_v8Hq     A                    0.867    1       0        0.0667
#> # ... with 70 more rows, and 9 more variables: covariate_cont_z <dbl>,
#> #   covariate_cont_a <dbl>, covariate_cont_b <dbl>, covariate_cont_c <dbl>,
#> #   covariate_cont_d <dbl>, covariate_cont_e <dbl>, covariate_cont_f <dbl>,
#> #   covariate_cont_g <dbl>, covariate_cont_h <dbl>
```

```r
library(haven)

write_sav(my_data, "my_data.sav")
```

---

*SPSS syntax*

```
GLM ws_x1_y1 ws_x1_y2 ws_x2_y1 ws_x2_y2 WITH covariate_dichoto covariate_cont_z covariate_cont_a 
    covariate_cont_b covariate_cont_c covariate_cont_d covariate_cont_e covariate_cont_f 
    covariate_cont_g covariate_cont_h
  /WSFACTOR=ws_x 2 Polynomial ws_y 2 Polynomial 
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
  /WSDESIGN=ws_x ws_y ws_x*ws_y
  /DESIGN=covariate_dichoto covariate_cont_z covariate_cont_a covariate_cont_b covariate_cont_c 
    covariate_cont_d covariate_cont_e covariate_cont_f covariate_cont_g covariate_cont_h.
```

---

**SPSS Results**

*I extracted just the results that are in the focus of the question.*

| Tests of Within-Subjects Effects |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure: | MEASURE_1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Source |  | Type III Sum of Squares | df | Mean Square | F | Sig. |
| ws_x * ws_y | Sphericity Assumed | 0.013 | 1 | 0.013 | 1.041 | 0.311 |
|  | Greenhouse-Geisser | 0.013 | 1.000 | 0.013 | 1.041 | 0.311 |
|  | Huynh-Feldt | 0.013 | 1.000 | 0.013 | 1.041 | 0.311 |
|  | Lower-bound | 0.013 | 1.000 | 0.013 | 1.041 | 0.311 |
| ws_x * ws_y * covariate_cont_z | Sphericity Assumed | 0.053 | 1 | 0.053 | 4.161 | 0.045 |
|  | Greenhouse-Geisser | 0.053 | 1.000 | 0.053 | 4.161 | 0.045 |
|  | Huynh-Feldt | 0.053 | 1.000 | 0.053 | 4.161 | 0.045 |
|  | Lower-bound | 0.053 | 1.000 | 0.053 | 4.161 | 0.045 |

Circling back to the opening of this post: now that I have `ws_x * ws_y` non-significant but `ws_x * ws_y * covariate_cont_z` as significant, what further steps in SPSS can I take to describe *how* `covariate_cont_z` exerts its moderating effect on the interaction of `ws_x` and `ws_y`?

One further exploration step I've already taken is by testing `covariate_cont_z` as the only covariate. Surprisingly (or not), `ws_x * ws_y * covariate_cont_z` p-value then was above 0.05. So only under the full 10-covariate model above do I get `covariate_cont_z` as "significant".

Comment: What is your dependent variable? Is it the four columns for the x and y values?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, yes, exactly.